# How do I apply the Pumping Lemma to prove that this language is not regular?

Tags: finite-automata, pumping-lemma

I am trying to teach myself Automata theory. I have hard time with the Pumping Lemma, so I am trying to work through examples. I stumbled upon this example, but it doesn't have steps how to solve it.
I would appreciate a clear explanation of how I would use the Pumping Lemma to prove that this language S is not regular:

$$
S = \{va^{7|v|}\text{ | }v \in \{a,b\}^*\}
$$
|v| = length of v

How do I use the Pumping Lemma to show that S is not regular?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am not sure where to put p in the equation.

Comment: Please write the details of your attempt (in the OP). Start with what you did manage to do, and compare it to examples you've seen. Once we see where you were going, we can give a good answer.

Comment: I understand example like S = a^n b^n. We can just put p instead on n like so a^p b^p and therefore xy can be a^p. But I am confused how to decide where to insert p in an uneven equation like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assume S is regular.

The pumping lemma says: There is a pumping length n. And if you take any string w in S with length > n, then w contains a non-empty substring in the first n symbols that can be repeated 0, 2, 3, 4, ... times, and the result is in the language. (Why is that? A regular language has a finite state machine. If that state machine has n states, then while you are processing the first n symbols, you must enter one state twice, say the state X. So you could take the symbols that took you from X back to X, and remove them, or duplicate them, or repeat them a million times, and your string would still be in the language). So w = xyz, xy has length ≤ n, y has length ≥ 1, and xz, xyz, xyyyyyyyyyz etc. are all in the language.

Take any string v with length k > n which doesn't end in a. The string w = v a^(7k) is in the language. When we split w into xyz, since the length of xy must be at most n, but v has a length k > n, we actually split into $w = xyz a^{7k}$.

The pumping lemma says that $xy^mz a^{7k}$ is in the language for every y. But for m ≠ 1, 7k is not seven times the length of $xy^mz$ so it is not in the language, therefore S is not regular.

Comment: "Take any string v with length k > n which doesn't end in a"
Question: why is it important for v to not end in a?

Comment: Because that way the last letters of x y^m z cannot become part of the a^(7k). If v ends in a, then I can insert 8a’s before the last a, increase k by 1, and move 7a’s into the a^(7k).